# How to write text on an image in Java?

Tags: android, android-studio

I simply want to create MEME Generator app.

For that purpose I need a `custom View` which consists of an `EditText`.
After entering the data, it turns to a TextView or the EditText becomes unEditable.
Then it can write out the desired image.
And lets me save the combined result to a JPEG.

Comment: please clarify your needs and show us what you have tried .

Comment: Your question has no sense. I guess you have used some translator, right?

Comment: please Explain you question with some detail

Comment: Simply you need a customView like https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Sticker+View&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults or you can Convert these View to your

Answer (score 0):

**simply use the framelayout for overlaping two views**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frmImageContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

<ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```